# ASP.NET WebForms - How to clean up registered user controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, user-controls

I inherited an ASP.NET WebForms project where all user controls are registered in Page instead of web.config file.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="header" Src="Controls/Header.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="footer" Src="Controls/Footer.ascx" %>
...
```

I want to make a cleanup, because some of those controls are not used on a page. Does Visual Studio have an option like "Organize Usings -> Remove Unused Usings" for user controls?

I'm also using Resharper but I couldn't find that option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper 6 does this. Register directives which are not used on the page give you a contextual "Register Directive is unused and can be safely removed" action option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such tool but generally you can use `Find` to quickly identify if user control has been used on the page or not - for example, searching for `uc:header` phrase will tell if header control has been used or not on that page. If same controls and tag-prefixes are used (a likely chance) then you can do *Find In All Files*.

Also registering controls in web.config is not necessarily a good idea. It should be done for controls (such as header/footer) that are used on most/many pages but for controls used on specific page or few pages, it make sense to use page specific register syntax.